# Download a file with JUST the filename from Google Drive using Python

Tags: python, download, upload, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file (that is uploaded just now) from Google Drive, but I don't have the file ID, so how can I download that file?

Is there any way to get the file ID? Is there any way to download that file without needing the file ID?

**EDIT:**  If it is not possible, where can I upload and download files easily with python?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `id` very easily with the [`Files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list). You only have to use the `q` parameter looking for the filename like `name = 'My filename here'`. You can check the [search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms) to learn how to finetune your search.

Comment: Can you please write an example with python?

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) you have a working example of the Drive API over Python by just following the steps described. After running this example, you only have to update the `main()` function to include [`Files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).